# Construct a matrix given a relation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider a $n\times n $ matrix $A \in M(\mathbb R)$ satisfying the relation:
$$A^b = - aI , \quad \text{ where $a > 0$ and $b$ is even}.$$
Is there an easy way to construct such a matrix?

If it is easier for the construction, consider $n = 8$, $b = 16$ and $a = 4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A=\begin{bmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$ satisfies $A^2=-I$, so $B=\sqrt{a}A$ satisfies $B^2=-aI$. If you want an $8\times 8$ matrix, just put 4 copies of $B$ on the diagonal.

For general $0\neq b\in\mathbb{Z}$, the matrix 
$$ A=\begin{bmatrix}\cos\frac{\pi}{b}&-\sin\frac{\pi}{b}\\\sin\frac{\pi}{b}&\cos\frac{\pi}{b}\end{bmatrix} $$
satisfies $A^b=-I$, then proceed as above.

Comment: Thank you for your answer (upvoted), but what if $n = 5$? Is there an easy approach?

Comment: That might be a bit tougher. What makes my answer work for $n=2$ is that I can turn a root of unity into an element of $\mathrm{SO}(2)$.

Comment: Yes, I got your thought! Anyway, thank you!

Comment: Actually, now that I think about it, if $b$ is even and $n$ is odd then such an $A$ cannot be found, because $\det(A^b)=\det(A)^b$ is positive while $\det(-aI)=(-a)^n$ is negative.

Comment: Yeap, you are right!